# OracleSql Join several column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a service table:

| id | service |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | ser_1 |
| 22 | ser_2 |
| 33 | ser_3 |
| 44 | ser_4 |
| 55 | ser_5 |
| 66 | ser_6 |
| 77 | ser_7 |
| 88 | ser_8 |

also, A combination of these services creates a new service
and a table like this:

| offer_1 | offer_2 | offer_3 | combination | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 22 | 33 | comb_1 | 300 |
| 11 | 33 |  | comb_2 | 200 |
|  | 44 | 22 | comb_3 | 100 |
| 44 |  | 11 | comb_4 | 100 |
| 55 |  |  | comb_5 | 150 |
| 11 | 22 | 44 | comb_6 | 200 |
|  |  | 77 | comb_7 | 400 |
|  | 22 | 11 | comb_8 | 150 |
|  | 88 |  | comb_9 | 250 |

It is also possible that any of the services were not in the new service table,
for example: id = 66

There is a user table:

| u_id | name | service_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | John | 11 |
| 12 | John | 22 |
| 12 | John | 33 |
| 12 | John | 77 |
| 14 | Kate | 44 |
| 14 | Kate | 11 |
| 15 | George | 11 |
| 15 | George | 33 |
| 16 | Bob | 55 |
| 17 | Alice | 44 |
| 17 | Alice | 22 |
| 18 | Ann | 77 |
| 18 | Ann | 88 |
| 18 | Ann | 22 |
| 19 | Fred | 66 |

I want to get such a table:

| u_id | name | combination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | John | comb_1 |
| 12 | John | comb_7 |
| 14 | Kate | comb_4 |
| 15 | George | comb_2 |
| 16 | Bob | comb_5 |
| 17 | Alice | comb_3 |
| 18 | Ann | comb_7 |
| 18 | Ann | comb_9 |

I tried but it does not work:

```
select ser.u_id,ser.name,c.combination,c.price
from
(select u.u_id,u.name,max(c1.offer_1) of1,max(c2.offer_2) of2,max(c3.offer_3) of3
  from user u
left join combination c1  on u.service_id = c1.offer_1
left join combination c2 on u.service_id = c2.offer_2 
left join combination c2 on u.service_id = c3.offer_3
  where u.service_id = (11,22,33,44,55,77,88)
group by u.u_id,u.name) ser
join combination c on ser.of1 = c.offer_1 and ser.of2 = c.offer_2 and ser.of3 = c.offer_3
```

Answer (score 0):

1 method to handle such a situation is to use LISTAGG before joining them -

```
SELECT U.u_id, U.name, O.combination
  FROM (SELECT u_id, name, LISTAGG(service_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY service_id) service_list
          FROM users
         GROUP BY u_id, name) U
  JOIN (SELECT combination, LISTAGG(offer, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY offer) offer_list
          FROM (SELECT offer_1 offer, combination
                  FROM offer_table
                 UNION ALL
                SELECT offer_2, combination
                  FROM offer_table
                 UNION ALL
                SELECT offer_3, combination
                  FROM offer_table)
         GROUP BY combination) O ON O.offer_list = U.service_list
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=00a5f58701f8b18e136b1d1676693de6)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but there is a situation when the user has a lot of services, for example: if John has four services (service_id in (11,12,33,55)), In this case, this method (listagg) will not work.  I want the combination table to be the main one and 
sort user services by combinations.

Comment: @sql_jr, Can you please post the sample data for the above example and expected result?

Comment: Can you please explain why u_id should have 2 rows with comb_1 and comb_7.

Comment: Because John has  the following services : 11,22,33,77.   A combination of 3 of these (11,22,33) creates a new service comb_1 and service_id = 77 is comb_7.